# Unable to use remaining accounts in anchor program sent from anchor-js?

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-lang, anchor-client

if i use remaining accounts that are sent from anchor js client in rust anchor program I am getting this error

> lifetime may not live long enough requirement occurs because of the
> type `anchor_lang::prelude::Account<'_, anchor_spl::token::TokenAccount>`, which makes the generic argument
> `'_` invariant the struct `anchor_lang::prelude::Account<'info, T>` is
> invariant over the parameter `'info`

This is my program code -

```
pub fn transfer_tokens<'info>(ctx: Context<TransferTokens<'info>>, token_amount: u64, bump: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let authority = ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info();
        let sender_tokens = &ctx.accounts.from_token_account;
        // let recipient_tokens = &ctx.accounts.to_token_account;
        let token_program = &ctx.accounts.token_program;
        let seeds: &[&[u8]] = &[
            b"authority",
            &[bump]
        ];  
        let signer_seeds:&[&[&[u8]]] = &[&seeds[..]];
        //recepient ATA is collected from remaining_accounts send from client 
        let toata:&AccountInfo<'info>= &ctx.remaining_accounts[1];
        
        token::transfer(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::Transfer {
                    from: sender_tokens.to_account_info(),
                    to: toata.to_account_info(),
                    authority: authority,
                },
                signer_seeds
            ),
            token_amount,
        )?;
        Ok(())
   }
```

This is anchor js code -

```
const tx = await program.methods.transferTokens(new BN(87),Bump)
                .accounts({
                      fromTokenAccount: fromAta.address,
                      tokenProgram:TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                      toTokenAccount: toAta,
                      authority: PDA
                })
                .remainingAccounts([{
                      pubkey: fromAta.address,
                      isWritable: true, // Set to true if the account should be writable
                    isSigner: false, // Set to true if the account is a signer
                  },
                  {
                    pubkey: toAta,
                    isWritable: true, // Set to true if the account should be writable
                    isSigner: false, // Set to true if the account is a signer
                  }
              ])
              .signers([])
              .rpc({});
```

How can I solve this lifetime error ? Any help will be much appreciated :))

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this error by adding explicit lifetime annotions:

```
pub fn transfer_tokens<'c: 'info, 'info>(
    ctx: Context<'_, '_, 'c, 'info, TransferTokens>,
    token_amount: u64,
    bump: u8
) -> Result<()> {
```

This is currently required for `remaining_accounts` usage in `anchor-lang 0.29.0`.

**Note:** The error is a Rust compile-time error so the JS code you've shared is irrelevant to the problem.

[Example](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/250fa8cdc508ab8035e19afdfb9ea208ccb46dbb/tests/misc/programs/remaining-accounts/src/lib.rs#L25-L27)